# Justification for specifying the parameters of prior mean distribution in stochastic volatility

Tags: bayesian, uninformative-prior

In a paper about the stochastic volatility, the author justifies his choice of prior distribution parameters $\pi(\mu) \sim \mathcal{N}(b_\mu,B_\mu) = \mathcal{N}(-9,0)$ of the level $\mu$ as follows:

*"common strategy is to choose a vague
prior here, e.g., c(0, 100), because the likelihood usually carries enough information about
this parameter. If one prefers to use (slightly) informative priors, e.g., to avoid outlier draws
of μ, one must pay attention to whether log returns or percentage log returns are analyzed.
Assuming daily data, log returns commonly have an unconditional variance of 0.0001 or less
and thus the level on the log scale μ lies around log(0.0001) ≈ −9. Percentage log returns,
on the other hand, have the 100^2 -fold unconditional variance (around 1) which implies a
level of log(1) = 0."*  [page 3 and 6 here](http://epub.wu.ac.at/4890/1/v69i05.pdf)

What I cannot understand, is why we use unconditional variance to specify the mean $b_\mu = -9$ of the prior distribution.